# Webpacker, Yarn and capistrano, fsevents@1.1.1 error

Tags: ruby, capistrano3, yarnpkg, fsevents, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a project that I recently migrate from rails 5.0 to rails 5.1, before this I had webpacker install and I deploy it with capistrano, in rails 5.0 everything was working, but when I did the change now capistrano is unable to finish the assets:precompile task and I get this error:

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
.....
DEBUG [04ae7a64] Command: cd /home/deploy/my-site/releases/20170602233846 && ( export RAILS_ENV="staging" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   yarn install v0.24.5

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   [1/4] Resolving packages...

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   [2/4] Fetching packages...

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   [3/4] Linking dependencies...

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   [4/4] Building fresh packages...

DEBUG [04ae7a64]   Done in 9.29s.

I'm using a local computer with ubuntu and ubuntu also is installed in the server.

I don't know where fsevents@1.1.1 is required as a dependency but I'm unabled to make deploy since 2 days ago and I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I think my original Webpacker installation must have gone wrong somehow. Using the master branch of webpacker and re-running `bundle exec rake webpacker:install` has fixed this issue.

---

**Original Answer:**
I came across this same error today. I think `./bin/yarn install --no-progress` which is what the Rails rake task naturally runs, must return a non-zero exit code.

Firstly I tried overriding the `yarn:install` rake task to add `--ignore-optional` but this didn't work.

I have got my deployment to succeed by adding the rake task `lib/tasks/yarn.rake` containing:

```
namespace :yarn do
  desc "Install all JavaScript dependencies as specified via Yarn"
  task :install do
    puts "Ignoring yarn install failure"

    begin
      system "./bin/yarn install --no-progress --ignore-optional; true"
    rescue
      exit(true)
    end

    exit(true)
  end
end

task(:default).clear.enhance(['yarn:install'])

# Run Yarn prior to Sprockets assets precompilation, so dependencies are available for use.
if Rake::Task.task_defined?("assets:precompile")
  Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance [ "yarn:install" ]
end
```

This replaces Rails' default yarn install rake task to pretty much ensure any errors aren't caught by Capistrano. This isn't a good solution, but at least it gets the deployment to succeed. Hopefully a legitimate yarn install error would lead to another error later in the assets build.